# How to mix namespaced mapGetters with global getters?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have namespaced one of my Vuex modules and I am unsure what syntax I should use for this scenario.

I am currently using this syntax where `dealfilters` is my namespaced module.

```
...mapGetters('dealfilters', [
    'dealCount',
    'pending',
    'arrival',
    'nights',
    'tag',
    'sortOptions'
])
```

How would I go about adding a global getter for this mapgetter helper again? Or even call multiple different namespaced modules inside the mapGetter?

Comment: What is the issue of calling twice `mapGetters` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using mapGetters twice. If you don't want to do that you can do the `namespace/getterName` string as well.

```
...mapGetters([
  'namespace_foo/thing',
  'namespace_foo/bazzle',
  'namespace_bar/thing',
  'not_namespaced_this_should_work_but_i_dont_know',
])
```